# How to implement simple message queue using nodejs worker threads?

Tags: node.js, concurrency, message-queue, node-worker-threads

I want implement simple message queue using nodejs worker threads. where one nodejs worker thread writes data to queue and when there is data in queue another worker thread takes that data and process the data.

Comment: see if this works for you https://dev.to/elasticrash/creating-a-simple-queue-messaging-application-over-http-using-nodejs-3ab2

Answer (score 0):

you can use redis pubsub to implement simple message queue, it also works with  multiple process.

Bull is Good Lib with UI. https://www.npmjs.com/package/bull